# Как узнать размер View в Android

Tags: android, java, canvas

Здравствуйте. Наследую класс View, т.е. пишу собственный пользовательский View. Для отрисовки всего необходимого в Canvas'е моего наследника класса View требуется знать заданный разметкой/кодом размер моего View'а.

Методы getWidth() и getHeight() из любого места в коде класса возвращают 0..

Отсюда вопрос, каким образом и когда получить реальный размер View'а? И вопрос вдогонку: каков полный жизненный цикл объекта-наследника View (по примеру Activity - во всех книжках по Android и статьях в интернете приводится диаграммка с порядком вызова callback-методов)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Размер `View` становится известным только после того как отработает `View.onMeasure()`, до этого он неизвестен, поскольку зависит от тучи факторов: соседние вьюшки, родители, размеры экрана и проч. проч. - так что размер замеряйте после или во время отработки `View.onMeasure()`. Вот что говорит мануал:

> A common mistake made by new Android
> developers is to use the width and
> height of a view inside its
> constructor. When a view’s constructor
> is called, Android doesn’t know yet
> how big the view will be, so the sizes
> are set to zero. The real sizes are
> calculated during the layout stage,
> which occurs after construction but
> before anything is drawn. You can use
> the onSizeChanged( )method to be
> notified of the values when they are
> known, or you can use the getWidth( )
> and getHeight( )methods later, such as
> in the onDraw( ) method.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Прямо в точку. Теперь больше познал эти View'ы.

Answer (score 0):

Во время отработки View.onMeasure() адекватный размер не удалось получить, а вот callback-метод onSizeChanged() в своих параметрах содержит как раз то что нужно.